# Google assistant is not working on linux

Tags: google-assistant-sdk, google-assist-api

I'm integrating google assistant on linux febora os. The latest version of google assistant is throwing an error for google-assistant-demo sample.

```
(env) [root@artik ~]# /env/bin/google-assistant-demo
usage: google-assistant-demo [-h] [--credentials OAUTH2_CREDENTIALS_FILE]
                             --device_model_id DEVICE_MODEL_ID
                             [--project_id PROJECT_ID]
google-assistant-demo: error: the following arguments are required: --device_model_id
```

I'm failing to registering the device model.

```
(env) [root@artik ~]# googlesamples-assistant-devicetool register --model 'my-model-identifier' \
>                                             --type LIGHT --trait action.devices.traits.OnOff \
>                                             --manufacturer 'Assistant SDK developer' \
>                                             --product-name 'Assistant SDK light' \
>                                             --description 'Assistant SDK light device' \
>                                             --device 'my-device-identifier' \
>                                             --nickname 'My Assistant Light'
Usage: googlesamples-assistant-devicetool register [OPTIONS]

Error: Missing option "--client-type".  Choose from SERVICE, LIBRARY
```

What is this register the device model? Google assistant will not work without registering the device model?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what issue you have. Can you not add the `client-type` argument to your command to register it?

```
(env) [root@artik ~]# googlesamples-assistant-devicetool register --model 'my-model-identifier' \
>                                             --type LIGHT --trait action.devices.traits.OnOff \
>                                             --manufacturer 'Assistant SDK developer' \
>                                             --product-name 'Assistant SDK light' \
>                                             --description 'Assistant SDK light device' \
>                                             --device 'my-device-identifier' \
>                                             --nickname 'My Assistant Light'
>                                             --client-type 'SERVICE'
```

Using the SDK expects a [Device Model and Device Id](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/guides/service/python/embed/register-device), as mentioned in the documentation.

If you're using the Google Assistant Library (with hotword) you should enter **LIBRARY**. Otherwise you should use **SERVICE**.

Answer (score 0):

Try to register the model online with the [Actions Console](https://console.actions.google.com)

Tutorial: [Register the Device Model](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/guides/library/python/embed/register-device)

Comment: Would you be able summarize the relevant content from the link in case it ever changes?